# NVidia driver thinks I'm using a screen that I'm not using

Tags: windows-10, display

I have 2 screens that I've been using until recently. I accidentally broke my 24" Samsung Curved monitor so I'm back to using my 18.5" AOC n941sw.

Unfortunately my Nvidia driver is displaying for the larger monitor so when I go 1366x768 (the AOC monitor's native resolution), it displays wrong. The recommended resolution is 1920x1080 which would be fine except that everything's tiny at this resolution on the smaller monitor.

I've tried reinstalling my graphics drivers but this hasn't helped. There are no drivers for the AOC monitor of which I'm aware and at this point, I only have the AOC monitor connected to the pc.

Rebooting doesn't help anything either.

I'm at a loss of what to do or what information to provide so if anyone can help in any way even if its just to identify what further information might be necessary, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If the Nvidia configuration is truly stuck, the best way to clear it out is to uninstall the Display Adapter in Device Manager.

Open the **Device Manager** and find and expand the **Display Adapters** section. Find your Nvidia GPU, right click on it, and select **Uninstall Device**. If prompted, uninstall the drivers as well.

Restart your computer and reinstall the drivers.